# how to rewrite URL having multiple parameters

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, search-engine

i have many pages having URL structure like this

```
http://yourwebsite.com/storename?oid=AA112&offid=6
```

how to make it SEO friendly URL as oid and offid denotes oid-orderid and offid-offerid.
these parameters refferes to a unique offers of a particular store which may change periodically

Comment: Which web server are you wanting help with?

Comment: i cant get you @mkaatman but i want to know is it ok if my url show like this indexed by google like this or i have to rewrite in some ways

Comment: @mkaatman asks you if you are using an apache webserver or what?Seo is a broad topic and yes clean url is a + for seo..

Comment: ya i am using apache server

Comment: is it good to use in Disallow: /*? in robot.txt to not index that url paramenter or any idea @mkaatman

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, here is one possible solution.

Make a single entry point. Then you need to write a router that handles a URL string

htaccess like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and router what do you want. very simple example:

```
$requestURI = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($requestURI[0] == 'index'){
    include('views/index.php');
}
```